# How to add file name to the top-right of a listing environment?

Tags: listings, code

I have several different `lstlisting` environments and was wondering if it were possible to add a box in the top-right corner of the environment that displays a string with the file name? For instance, if I have some code

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,frame=single]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

and I want to designate that this code belongs to `main.c`, is there a way I can show that with the style I'm after?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tcolorbox` which already comes loaded with many options. Refer to its documentation for more customisation.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[listings,skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lstdefinestyle{mycppstyle}{%
    language=C,
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    basewidth=0.5em,
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[1]{%
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    title={\texttt{#1}},
    attach boxed title to top right,
    listing options={style=mycppstyle}
}

\begin{mylisting}{main.c}
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
\end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]